# UICollectionView freezes iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

Good morning,

I'm using **UICollectionView** for the first time to show images from a user (like a Facebook profile) and at the moment I can show the images fine but I have some problems:

1- When I visit my profile the app freezes for like 2-3 minutes due to the load of 5 images.

2- When I'm moving through the **UICollectionView** it freezes when the app load again the images outside the screen.

***What I have to do in order to not to freeze the app when loading the user pictures? And what I have to do to navigate through the CollectionView without freezing? Maybe a cache system is what I need?***

That's my code:

**ProfileViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor: [self colorWithHexString:@"FFFFFF"]];

    self.profileimage.layer.cornerRadius = self.profileimage.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.profileimage.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.profileimage.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
    self.profileimage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

    [self fetchJson];
    [self fetchImages];

    self.oneCollectionView.dataSource = self;
    self.oneCollectionView.delegate = self;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _carImages.count;
}

// COLLECTION VIEW
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView
                                    dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"
                                    forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *data = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imagen"];
    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:data];
    NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage * images = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    myCell.imageview.image = images;

    return myCell;
}

-(void)fetchImages {

    self.carImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *usersPassword = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"login" account:@"account"];

    NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mywebsite.com/posts.php?usersPassword=%@",usersPassword];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

     NSError *error;
    [_jsonArray removeAllObjects];
    _jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization
                  JSONObjectWithData:data
                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                  error:&error];

    for(int i=0;i<_jsonArray.count;i++)
    {
        NSDictionary * jsonObject = [_jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString* imagen = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"imagen"];
        [_carImages addObject:imagen];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the actual image (with larger size) OR you have made thumbnails (with very small size foo displaying in `UICollectioViewCell`) ?

Comment: I'm using the actual image and inside the imageview I just tell the width and the height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the dispatcher to create an async operation for the download of the images. This will resolve the 2 problems you have:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:YOUR_IMAGE_URL];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
    [YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW_OUTLET performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:img waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

These are the snippet you have to change:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView
                                dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"
                                forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *data = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imagen"];
    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:data];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: imageURL];
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        [myCell.imageview performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:img waitUntilDone:YES];
    });

    return myCell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @LucaD, where I have to put that code? Much appreciated.

Comment: Where you use the +(NSData *)dataWithContentsOfURL: (NSURL *)url

Comment: When I use your code @LucaD the problems are resolved, but at the moment I have another one: The images are not showing until 3-5 seconds and then I can navigate through them without problems but it seems that it's taking so much time to load the images.

Comment: The delay is the time to download the images... Maybe you have to resize them

Comment: And what's exactly the last line? I didn't use it because I don't know exactly the @selector and the ViewOutlet.

Comment: How can I resize it? I'm passing the URL.

Comment: Last line means that you can not modify the GUI in a secondary thread, you have to do it on the Main Thread (performSelectorOnMainThread:). The selector means a method to call (setImage:) that is a method of each UIImageView Object. The viewOutlet is the property where is allocated the UIImageView

Comment: If the images are yours,you have to modify them and the re-upload the files. Maybe you have to search other photos...

Comment: Thanks @LucaD, so I don't have to change anything?

Comment: You have to change the code in uppercase that I wrote with yours.

Comment: How can I see which is my ViewOutlet?

Comment: You set many UIImageView (see at cellForItemAtIndexPath). You have to modify there and in -fetchImages

Comment: I'm a little bit lost because it's my first time using CollectionView, can you help me with more information? I don't know what I have to put in the "ViewOutlet". Thanks again.

Comment: I modified the post with the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Download the images asynchronously, `dataWithContentsOfURL` is synchronous method and it will block your current thread until the download completes. You can use libraries like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to automatically handle downloading for you or You can use `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` to download Images.

```
- (void)fetchImages {

    self.carImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *usersPassword = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"login" account:@"account"];

    NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mywebsite.com/posts.php?usersPassword=%@",usersPassword];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            [self.jsonArray removeAllObjects];
            self.jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:data
                              options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                              error:&error];

            for(int i=0;i<_jsonArray.count;i++)
            {
                NSDictionary * jsonObject = self.jsonArray[i];
                NSString* imagen = jsonObject[@"imagen"];
                [self.carImages addObject:imagen];
            }
        }

    }];
    [dataTask resume];

}

// COLLECTION VIEW

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
    cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView
                                    dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"
                                    forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *data = [[self.jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imagen"];
    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:data];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *imageDownloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession]
    downloadTaskWithURL:imageURL completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:
        [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location]];
        myCell.imageview.image = image;
    }];

    [imageDownloadTask resume];

    return myCell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Import `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h`

and load your image via this method in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-B8kSXtoaQDo/VGTVlXyIXpI/AAAAAAAAJ_M/USh6SgvMemw/w1024-h1024/IMG_20141112_103152.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder-avatar"]];
```

it will surely speed up to load and scrolling collectionView

Answer (score 0):

Try to Register Nib For Collection View

Write following code in your viewController's `viewDidLoad()`method :

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCollectionCell" bundle: nil];
[self.collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

And I think you have to use https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView for the image loading in collection view.

For Storyboards you have to see this tutorial : http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/ This will help you more.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Ashish, but where I have to write that code?

Comment: Thanks @Ashish, but it shows me that error: Could not load NIB in bundle. It's because I'm using storyboard?

Comment: I have added a link of tutorial, You have to see it. @Thomas_12

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check that :)

Comment: And If you are not using ARC then you have to retain your variables which you like to display in UICollectionViewCell @Thomas_12

Answer (score 0):

For the first question the answer is in this line of code:

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

From [Apple Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/index.html):

> Do not use this synchronous method to request network-based URLs. For
>   network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens
>   of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and
>   in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated.

As alternative you can use `NSURLSessionDataTask` to download data (see [Apple Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDataTask_class/index.html))

**-Edit**

In ProfileViewController.h add these two properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURLSession *session;
```

then, in `- viewDidLoad` initialise them:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view
    self.sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:self.sessionConfig];
    //Other stuff...
}
```

Finally, in ProfileViewController.m

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                 cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCollectionViewCell *myCell = [collectionView
                                    dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"
                                    forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *data = [[_jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"imagen"];
    NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:data];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *imageDownloadTask = [self.session dataTaskWithURL:imageURL
                                         completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                             if (error) {
                                                 NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
                                             } else {

                                                 NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                                                 if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
                                                     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

                                                      myCell.imageview.alpha = 0.0f;
                                                      myCell.imageview.image = image;
                                                      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.45 animations:^{
                                                             myCell.imageview.alpha = 1.0f;   
                                                     });
                                                 } else {
                                                     NSLog(@"Couldn't load image at URL: %@", imageURL);
                                                     NSLog(@"HTTP %d", (int)httpResponse.statusCode);
                                                 }
                                             }
                                         }];
    [imageDownloadTask resume];

    return myCell;

}
```

I hope this can help you.

**- Edit 2** 
For future readers, I slightly refactored my code based on @suhit's answer (+1 for him)

Comment: Why do you use this stuff when you can use the GCD?
Maybe is better if you use dispatcher to create an async operation.

Comment: @LucaD 'this stuff' is just what Apple has created in order to perform this kind of task. _The NSURLSession class and related classes provide an API for downloading content via HTTP. This API provides a rich set of delegate methods ...._ [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html). Anyway, my snippet didn't want to be perfect, but an useful answer that you can refactor how you like if you like.